# Give apache2 read permissions on Ubuntu

Tags: html, linux, ubuntu, apache2, chmod

I'm trying to serve a folder on an Apache2 web server as an "Index of" type page in an iframe. I have

```
<Directory /media/user/Lambda/files/archive>
        Options Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /archive /media/user/Lambda/files/archive
```

in my .conf file and

```
<iframe  src="/archive" title=" File Archive"></iframe>
```

on my webpage. All that shows up in the iframe is ***Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.*** I tried messing with chmod but I'm pretty inexperienced with Ubuntu and Linux, especially permissions. I've gathered I need to give Apache2 read permissions on /media/user/Lambda/files/archive, but I'm absolutly lost on how to do so.

Just in case this is important, running ls -l /media/user/Lambda/files/ returns:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 neon neon 4096 Jun 27 16:05 archive
```

'neon' is my username on this computer

Comment: apache2 runs as www-data user+group permission and you have to change the ownership to this user.
`sudo chgrp -R www-data /path_of_folder`

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work. Tried changing to the folder I host directly and one folder above that and I still get the forbidden error